# UIButton with two state - touch and long touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to make a button perform different methods, depending on if the user taps or does a long tap.

I've tried:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doRewind)];
[uiNextButton addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

But the app registers my touch only when I touch the button and move the finger a little bit.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your button the most front subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting both a "normal" tap and a "long" tap gesture, there could be interactions between the two of them.

Have you tried setting the `minimumPressDuration` property for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

Also, using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` can be useful to make one of the two gesture handler fire only if the other one did not.

Have a look at the [relevant document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) for those two methods.

If this does not help, please, give more details about your view and all the gesture handlers you are defining.