# UILongPressGestureRecognizer recognize only when moving my finger

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i try to use UILongPressGestureRecognizer in my App and the problem is that this function call only when i move my finger a little bit.

this is the code i am using :

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doRewind)];
    [uiNextButton addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Comment: in which method are you adding this code?

Comment: are you setting the long press interval?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIButton with two state - touch and long touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890603/uibutton-with-two-state-touch-and-long-touch)

Comment: @MTA: this is the exact same question you posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890603/uibutton-with-two-state-touch-and-long-touch/6890769#6890769. If you do not get any answer, the way to go is adding more details to your original question, not posting the same question again. Help the community keep S.O. a tidy place, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has been created with the bare minimum of configuration information. At a minimum you should look into setting these properties:

- minimumPressDuration
- allowableMovement

And in special cases you can also set:

- numberOfTouchesRequired
- numberOfTapsRequired

In your case I think you want to set the allowableMovement to 0, the default value is 10 (pixels). You can read more from the class reference I linked.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am late to answer this question, but I think this might help someone.
I was having the same problem. I needed to fire the event and move to the next screen without moving or touching up my screen. As the gesture recognizer has different states:

`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`

I was using `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` and that was creating the problem, because it first checks if the state has begun and the event was not firing without moving my finger.
So I replaced my `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state with
`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` and everything worked fine.
Now you don't need to move your finger away. Just touch hold and everything work fine.

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
     // Do your stuff
}
```

Thats the correct way, other ways like `numberOfTapsRequired`, `allowableMovement` are meant for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

When adding the UILongPressGestureRecognizer, you also need to set the interval for which you want the user to hold. You can do this with the following line of code:

```
[longPress setMinimumPressDuration:2];
```

Comment: No, you don't have to set it. It has a [default value of 0.5 s](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer/1616423-minimumpressduration)